# Equivalent to LIST() in Firebird 1.5

Tags: sql, firebird

The LIST() function available in Firebird 2.1 onwards (http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-aggrfunc-list.html) is exactly what I need. Unfortunately I'm stuck with Firebird 1.5. After doing some searching I haven't found an alternative I could get to work.

Essentially I want to aggregate a bunch of rows into a comma separated string in Firebird 1.5.

Comment: You may write a stored procedure which will do what you want

Comment: You really should consider spending time to upgrade. By now Firebird 1.5 is 12 years old and hasn't had any updates (and that includes fixes of security problems) for 7 years.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this routine

```
create or alter procedure GETSTRFROMSQL
(
  SQLSTR blob sub_type text,
  SEPARATOR varchar(32)
)
returns
(
  OUTSTR blob sub_type text
)
as
declare tmpstr blob sub_type text;
begin
  outstr = '';
  for execute statement sqlstr
  into tmpstr do
  begin
    if (outstr = '')then
      outstr = tmpstr;
    else
      outstr = outstr || separator || tmpstr;
  end
  suspend;
end
```

Usage example (the first param is your sql, which should return only one column):

```
select * from getstrfromsql('select 1 from rdb$database union select 2 from rdb$database', ',')
```

Of course it's better to upgrade to 2.5 or 3.0, but unfortunately in those versions there is no possibility to order by values in list(), so this routine can be useful anyway